# TypeError: message.client.commands.array is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanted to update my help command from djs v12.5.3 to v13 but I got this error: `TypeError: message.client.commands.array is not a function`

Here is my code I used before:

```js
let commands = message.client.commands.array();
commands.forEach((cmd) => {
    if(cmd.name == args[0].toLowerCase() || cmd.aliases.includes(args[0].toLowerCase())) {
                    embed.addField("**Description**", `${cmd.description}`, false)
                    embed.addField("**Usage**", `${cmd.usage}`, true)
                    embed.addField("**Aliases**", `${cmd.alias}`, true)
                    embed.addField("**Examples**", `${cmd.examples}`, true)
                    message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] });
    }
})
```

I tried changing `let commands = message.client.commands.array();` to `let commands = message.client.commands.values();` but got another error: `TypeError: commands.forEach is not a function`!
How can I list my commands again on v13?

Comment: Log `message.client.commands`, what kind of data/class does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[That function was removed](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#collection). Instead of `.array`, you need to do the following:

```js
let commands = [...message.client.commands.values()]
```

However there is no reason to convert, unless you want to display all the values easily.

`message.client.commands.each` will work just fine

```js
message.client.commands.each((cmd) => {})
```

Comment: `Array.from(message.client.commands.values())` is also an option

Comment: Yes, but this *is* shorter syntax