# Entering to a Collection Discord.js v13

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I recently updated to v13, and I had some commands where i transform Objects to arrays using .array(), but now it gives my an error saying that .array() isn't a function
How can I enter to the information in a Collection now?

```
msg.array()[0].embeds[0]
```

This is an example of what I used to do

```
TypeError: mensajes.array is not a function
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: message.client.commands.array is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69486654/typeerror-message-client-commands-array-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Collection>.array()` has been removed in discord.js

If you need to convert a collection to an array of values similar to the old method, use `Array.from(<Collection>.values())`

But in your case, I don't see a need to convert to an array in the first place.
If you want to get the first element in the collection, it would be much more efficient to use `<Collection>.first()`.

Comment: really thx you <3, I have to collect information from 5 diferent things, thats why is more easy that way